# Is there any good book regarding 3D reconstruction from 2D images? I prefer to work in MATLAB

Tags: computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am working on a project regarding 3D reconstruction of 2D images. I have understanding of finding and Mathcing the keypoints and its algorithms; but i am not able to replicate the theory in MATLAB code. Is there any Book or paper which is basic for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of good books. [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/),

"[Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/)", but anyway, replication of the theory is the necessary stage to me.

You can start from the finishing course "[3D Computer Vision](https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/wiki/courses/a4m33tdv/start)" from the CTU. They published lectures and labs - in MatLAB.

P.S. Here is a ready implementation http://www.fit3d.info/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these examples from the Computer Vision System Toolbox:

- [Sparse 3-D Reconstruction From Multiple Views](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html)
- [Stereo Calibration and Scene Reconstruction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html)